# What is the use of php bin/magento dev:di:info command?

Tags: magento2.3, di, magento2.3.4

With Magento 2.3, console command found which helps developers to find all the classes related to dependency injection.

It seems that it shows dependency Injection classes from `di.xml` from all areas.

Ques: Does anyone know whether it shows which modules do have a dependency on which modules?

Comment: It does give plugins info (i.e) bin/magento dev:di:info Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product, but DI preference no luck

Answer (score 2):

you can Use the **dev:di:info** command to retrieve information about dependency injection configuration for a class. Like if you want to retrieve information for class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product then run the command `bin/magento dev:di:info "Magento\Catalog\Model\Product"` from your command line. you'll get output something like this.
[image]

you can get info of your custom class or any vendor class.

Comment: An another example would be bin/magento dev:di:info "Magento\Search\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source\Engine". The command lists the versions of Elasticsearch in the column "configured values"

Answer (score 2):

**Ques : What is the use of php bin/magento dev:di:info command?**

Answer :

```
bin/magento dev:di:info "<class-namespace>"
```

This Command Will Generate the List of the preferences and plugins (after, around and before) which is used for the particular class.

Official Reference :
[Magento Devdocs - Info Di List](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/build/dependency-injection-file/#get-dependency-injection-configuration-information-for-a-class)
[image]

**Ques : Does anyone know whether it shows which modules do have a dependency on which modules?**

Answer :

For this you can use the command :

```
bin/magento info:dependencies:show-modules
```

It will generate the csv file at magento root (modules-dependencies.csv), If the path is not specified in the command.

You can learn, more about this command in the Official Document :
[Magento Devdocs - Info Dependencies](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cli/dependency-reports.html)
[image]

So from the above two commands, You can catch the particular Module or Class for development purpose or for debugging.

Happy Coding !!